# IIS Slow Outside localhost

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I've a production server with Windows 2003 Server (IIS 6). It has 1 GB RAM and 2 web sites configured on it and 8 Application Pools.
There is one specific page which sometimes starts to run too slow (about 150 secs) when is called from outside the server, the strange thing is when you call it from inside:

```
http://localhost/bla-bla.aspx
```

the response time is immediate.

The rest of the sites on the web server run Okay, either from inside or outside.

The CPU is about 30%, and the memory consumption is below 1 GB.

The page which is running too slow is on it's own Application Pool.
If I restart that Application Pool, nothing happens: It keeps running too slow when is called from outside the server.
But if I restart the IIS, then it runs Okay for about 15 minutes, and then it starts to run slow again.

This is a server with thousands of daily hits, the size of the logfiles are about 400 Mb per day, and apparently that page starts to run slowly during peak hours.

The weird thing is that when this page begins to run slowly, the CPU and RAM seems to be Okay. And also why it runs Okay from localhost?

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Exemplify what 'outside' means (and doesn't mean) to you.

Comment: I mean from other host except than "localhost". Suppose that the server is called: "myserver.com" If I call from machine B to "myserver.com": `http://myserver.com/blah-blah.aspx` then it runs slow, but if I do the same from inside the server "myserver.com" by typing: `http://localhost/blah-blah.aspx` then it runs Okay. ¿Any ideas?

Comment: Does it contain anything that does DNS lookups?

Comment: @enieloud, you need to check out coding side, double check your web.config and application pool